# Are "MOAB SHREDR" Spike factory's faster than 0-2 Spike factory's?

Tags: bloons-td-5, bloons-monkey-city

I've been playing BTD5 and BMC, and whenever I upgrade the spike factory from 0-2 to 0-3, it seems to make spikes **FASTER** than a normal 0-2 spike factory. Is it just me, or are they faster?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the right path tier 3 upgrade for a Spike Factory (MOAB-SHREDR) increases the speed as well as the damage to MOAB class bloons.

Source:  http://btd-5.wikia.com/wiki/Spike_Factory

> Effect: Each spike does 4 damage to M.O.A.B. Class Bloons. Also shoots at a faster rate.

See also:  http://bloons.wikia.com/wiki/Spike_Factory

> Attack rate improves to once every 18 frames, or half a second.